# LED strip light won't work... sorta

Tags: motor-controller, led-driver, led-strip

Making a lamp using a <strike>DPDT</strike> SPDT ON-OFF-ON toggle. ON1 is the lamp. No issues there. ON2 is going to be an LED strip in the base to function as a nightlight. The single-color LED strip is what's leftover from another project, for which I used the power adapter that came with the lights.

I have an APV-8-5 to drive the LEDs. This goes to a DC 6-35V 5A Motor Speed Regulator which I'm using as a dimmer. Beautiful. Everything works perfectly. I can turn 'em off and have a perfect range of brightnesses, no flicker.

The "dimmer" is hidden. I want to be able to set it, but then use the toggle on the front to turn on either the lamp or nightlight. But when I switch to ON2, nada. I have to turn the pot off and then back on to get the nightlight to turn on, and then after that everything works perfectly. I tried wiring it without the regulator, but the LEDs don't come on at all now.

So, feel free to talk to me like I'm an idiot, because clearly I am. I've built basic lamps, but know very little about these strip LEDs. My goal here is to be able to flip the toggle and have the LEDs come on.

Why must I have a switch in the DC portion of the circuit for this to work? Is there anything I can do to change that?

[image: Attempt at a diagram below:]

Comment: "So, feel free to talk to me like I'm an idiot, because clearly I am." 
1) Don't talk down to yourself like that. Negativity never helps with troubleshooting.
2) Do you have any schematic you can include? That would help a lot.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I'm a hobbyist. I know enough make sure the wide blade goes to the ribbed wire goes to the silver terminal. (OK, maybe a bit more than that, but not enough to a diagram.)

Comment: OK, first, it is a SPDT switch that I'm using. Sorry. And, not that I think it matters, it is an ON-OFF-ON. I wasn't sure how to indicate the OFF state.

I just added a diagram to the original message. Thanks!

Comment: Most important would be the model and preferably the documentation for the motor speed regulator. The LED strip isn't the problem.

Comment: Thanks @pipe. I don't have a model number and there isn't anything on the part itself. It's this: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B091SHPR6L . I just noticed the 3-15v label and the note that "3-9v input needs short circuit." I'm guessing that's the issue, that I need to short that... but I'm not certain enough to take the whole thing apart again, yet.

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case, I can try to figure something out for hours, but as soon as I make a post asking for help, I figure it out on my own.

It was as I said in my last comment. I had to short the 3-15v terminals.